# размытое изображение на подключенном втором экране от ноутбука windows 10

Tags: windows-10, экран, intel, монитор

У меня ноутбук с разрешением 1920X1080 60 кадров в секунду, но когда я подключаю второй монитор, поддерживающий 4K 165Гц, изображение на нем размывается. Мониторы используют встроенную графику Intel. Подключаются по hdmi

Монитор 2
[image: Монитор 2]

Монитор 1 (ноут)
[image: Монитор 1]

Когда добавляю кастомное разрешение экрана в настройках из списка поддерживаемых, то выдает ошибку что не поддерживается...

Comment: у тебя точно не в режиме mirroring работает подключенный монитор?

Comment: @xmikex точно, экраны разделены. Даже если отключить экран ноутбука ничего не меняется